# border not have round limits - css

Tags: css, angular, sass, primeng

How can I fix the bottom border to have round limits?
All I need is the solid line will be rounded, and As my table coded the line is not rounded

```
 <p-table [value]="fg?.controls?.treesSummary?.controls" styleClass="sumTable">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
          <tr>
          </tr>
          <tr *ngFor="let item of  fg?.controls?.treesSummary?.controls; let i = index" [formGroupName]="i" class="gray-border">
            <th class="th_first_t">
              <input type="number" [attr.disabled]="true" #ddNames [value]="this?.fg?.get('treesSummary')?.controls[0]?.get('copying')?.value +
              this?.fg?.get('treesSummary')?.controls[0]?.get('unproot')?.value +
              this?.fg?.get('treesSummary')?.controls[0]?.get('conservation')?.value"
              digitOnlyTextBox pInputText />
            </th>
            <th class="th"><input type="number" #ddNames digitOnlyTextBox formControlName="conservation" pInputText /></th>
            <th class="th"><input type="number" #ddNames digitOnlyTextBox formControlName="copying" pInputText /></th>
            <th class="th_last_t"><input type="number" #ddNames digitOnlyTextBox formControlName="unproot" pInputText /></th>

          </tr>
        </ng-template>

      </p-table>
```

*css*

```
.gray-border {
  border-left: 1px solid gray;
  border-right: 1px solid gray;
  border-bottom: 1px solid gray;
}
.th_last_t {
    border-radius: 0px 0 0 15px !important;
    background-color: red !important;
}
.th_first_t {
  border-radius: 0 0px 15px 0 !important;
  background-color: #edf3fb !important;
}
```

[image: not round limits]
rounded with flex
[image]

Comment: that line is from the parent element, round it too

Comment: @MANSOORKOCHY thanks but it doesn't change it

Comment: where is the border line came from? I mean which element?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding the question correctly, I think you need to add the border radius to .gray-border as well:

```
.gray-border {
  ...
  border-radius: 0 0 15px 15px;
}
```

I noticed that you also need to swap the border radius for th_first_t and th_last_t to be like this:

```
.th_last_t {
    ...
    border-radius: 0 0px 15px 0 !important;
}
.th_first_t {
    ...
    border-radius: 0px 0 0 15px !important;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ds0uph3v/

Comment: thanks but it doesn't change it

Comment: @Kate - Please see updated answer

Comment: thank you! me problem is with display:flex. when I'm adding it its make the border rounded but it moves all the inputs to one th

Comment: I added picture to my question, thanks

Comment: You probably don't need the display flex for what you're doing, that was just so I could easily get all the divs in a row.

Comment: its weired because when removing it its removing the rounded border

Comment: Maybe try this? https://dev.to/temmietope/rounded-edges-on-table-rows-1d0n